# Swap not availlable

Tags: encryption, swap

I have noticed that my swap is not available. This could explain why my computer freezes every so often when I am using it heavily.

I installed 14.04 64-bit with an encrypted folder, which automatically encrypts my swap. This used to work perfectly in 12.04 64-bit.

The relevant lines from `/etc/fstab` are:

```
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
#UUID=5e37c9cd-ba35-4907-8c77-556a308d1491  none  swap  sw  0  0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1                      none  swap  sw  0  0
```

`sudo blkid` does not list the swap:

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="PQSERVICE" UUID="FA3A29383A28F375" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda2: LABEL="SYSTEM RESERVED" UUID="967CF34F7CF3291F" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda3: LABEL="Daisy PC" UUID="36027B05027AC97F" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda5: LABEL="DaisyHome" UUID="4ad946a8-3a8e-41b9-907c-258b2ad9544e" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda7: LABEL="DaisyRoot" UUID="5cb3c1ff-fdd2-458b-9765-b9407d19b469" TYPE="ext4"
```

System Monitor shows swap as being unavailable.

[image: Swap not available in System Monitor]

Gparted shows the swap partition as "unknown".

[image: GIMP swap partition unknown]

Disks shows the swap partition as "Linux Swap", but is unable to mount the partition.

[image: Disks Linux partition]

I have been Googling, reading Ubuntu Forums and searching this forum, and have been unable to find anything that helps to re-enable the swap.

Can you help, please.

**EDIT**

The file `/etc/crypttab` confusingly has two lines:

```
cryptswap1 UUID=5e37c9cd-ba35-4907-8c77-556a308d1491 /dev/urandom swap,cipher=aes-cbc-essiv:sha256
cryptswap1 UUID=7426472f-9ec1-4e53-b8e1-930e3d6f73fc /dev/urandom swap,cipher=aes-cbc-essiv:sha256
```

Here is a list of the UUIDs on my system:

```
$ ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun 20 08:48 36027B05027AC97F -> ../../sda3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun 20 08:48 4ad946a8-3a8e-41b9-907c-258b2ad9544e -> ../../sda5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun 20 08:48 5cb3c1ff-fdd2-458b-9765-b9407d19b469 -> ../../sda7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun 20 08:48 967CF34F7CF3291F -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun 20 08:48 FA3A29383A28F375 -> ../../sda1
```

Now my problem is: How do I determine the UUID of `/dev/sda6`? Is this even possible on an encrypted swap? Finally, how do I fix `/etc/crypttab`?

Comment: Can you check to see that `/etc/crypttab` has the right partition listed?

Comment: @saiarcot895 — I have added the information as an edit to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to your comments, @saiarcot895, on further investigation I have discovered what to do.

I have edited `/etc/crypttab` to remove the extra line (there was also an extra line in `/etc/fstab`, which I removed), and to replace UUID with the partition reference. Hence:

```
cryptswap1 /dev/sda6 /dev/urandom swap,cipher=aes-cbc-essiv:sha256
```

I would still like to know how to replace the partition reference with the UUID, but perhaps that's not possible with an encrypted swap.

**EDIT:**

As far as I can tell, the UUID of an encrypted partition is unavailable until that partition has been decrypted. I have discovered that in the case of an encrypted swap using a random key each boot, the UUID changes each time. Therefore, the UUID is not useful in specifying which encrypted partition to mount.

This can cause a serious problem with removable disks!

Comment: `sudo blkid /dev/sda6` will give you the UUID.

Comment: @saiarcot895, unfortunately not. I have tried using `sudo blkid` both from my normal session and from a Live USB, but it seems that no UUID is available for an encrypted partition.

Answer (score 0):

run `cfdisk` re-create the swap partition.
run command

`# mkswap /dev/sda6`

then

`# swapon /dev/sda6`

mind that sda6 is your swap partition

Comment: I don't know the command `cfdisk`. I could use `gparted` to reformat the swap partition. However, what you propose will create a non-encrypted swap, which is not recommended when using encrypted folders.