# No Swap Space Available?

Tags: partitioning, encryption, swap

I'm running Kubuntu 17.10, and I've noticed that there doesn't appear to be any swap space available. This is a system upgrade from 17.04. I'm running an encrypted home folder, but no full disk encryption (I'm pretty sure about the full disk encryption, but I'm not 100% sure, and I'm not sure how to check if I am). How can I restore the swap system? I know that Kubunu 17.* changed how the swap system works, so I don't think previous solutions (Such as [Swap not availlable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/485661/swap-not-availlable?rq=1)) are applicable.

Note the swap space notification on the lower right
[image: System Moniter]

**EDIT 0:** 
Output of `cat /etc/fstab`

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name     devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
    UUID=4498e4cd-fef7-4d1f-843b-60054064dea9 /               ext4            errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
#UUID=C7BD-3586  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw                  0       0
    #/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
UUID=C7BD-3586  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1`
```

**EDIT 1:**
Output of `ls -lah /swapfile`

`-rw------- 1 root root 2.0G Aug 19 15:04 /swapfile`

**EDIT 2:** This question is distinct from ([Incredibly reluctant swapping](https://askubuntu.com/questions/973905/incredibly-reluctant-swapping)) due to the nature of the swap space. On diagnostic tools, there *doesn't appear to be any swap space*, as seen in the lower right hand corner of the System Monitor picture. The swap space is not *reluctant*, *it simply doesn't exist* according to the system diagnostic tools. Additionally, the behavior of the swap space varies as well. The system will never put RAM to the disk, *ever*. As the system RAM becomes more saturated, system performance degrades, and as it hits the limit, the system seizes, and never returns. This is clearly divergent behavior from [Incredibly reluctant swapping](https://askubuntu.com/questions/973905/incredibly-reluctant-swapping)

Comment: Please add the output of `cat /etc/fstab` by [edit]ing your question.

Comment: It shows you have a swap file, this is located in `/`. check it's size

Comment: @Videonauth no such functionality occurs, when I run out of RAM, the computer simply freezes indefinitely.  Also, `TaskManager` simply says that it doesn't exist, although this could be a bug in task manager.

Comment: O.k. what is the output of `ls -lah /swapfile` maybe it didn't get created.

Comment: if  swap partition is available, it can be added also.

Comment: It may be that your swapfile was not correctly created, or has become corrupt.  Please see [https://askubuntu.com/a/974807/283721](https://askubuntu.com/a/974807/283721)

Comment: Or read `man mkswap;man swapon;man ecryptfs-setup-swap`

Comment: In your case, I would turn off swap, run `sudo mkswap /swapfile` and turn swap back on.  Then check swap status with `swapon`

Comment: @CharlesGreen Ok, so I did your instructions, and system manager registers the new swap space. I assume I can use it, but I'll have to go over-memory to test it.

Comment: Sounds promising so far

Comment: @CharlesGreen Ok, the swap space functions. I tested it by opening a lot of Youtube tabs, the system went over the RAM limit and started using swap, although, there was a considerable system slowdown, as expected when using Disk space.

Comment: Okay - ill turn that into an answer then, tomorrow  morning

Comment: @CharlesGreen No, is wasn't reluctant, it just *never* worked. Ever, if the computer approached 95% and then transitioned to full, the computer simply froze, and never returned. Additionally, there was no swap space listed in System Moniter.

Comment: @Sarah I understand what you're saying, but the answer is the same in either case. I wrote both of them in fact. I am linking this question to that question because I believe that their reluctance into you swap in the other questions case and your non-functional swap are caused by the same root problem

Comment: Hopefully, having the questions point at each other will make it easier for future users to find a good answer